# Need Practical Public Photography Guides?

Tags: street-photography

I'm looking for a general guide for public photography. Is there a set of regulations that applies to various kinds of locations? Any recommendations on where to go first to begin obtaining licenses in other countries?

Comment: Hi Silva and welcome to Photo.SE! Please take a moment to take the [tour] to be able to optimally make use of this site. Currently your question is a bit vague (to me) and does not show previous research. Have you looked into [previous](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/97910/9161) possibly [related](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/25876/9161) questions? Perhaps you've done some web searches which came up empty? Please include all that in your question such that we know what you've tried so far and in what direction you're looking.

Comment: When I redirected you from [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/178188/need-practical-public-photography-guides) to here, I specifically said "it will need to be an actual question which can be answered, rather than a vague request for help". I'm closing this, because it's still a vague request for help rather than an actual question; it can be reopened if it is made into an actual question (and not one which requests off-site resources, a category of questions which is off-topic across every Stack Exchange site).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you were given some indications when you posed the question; you can view them, but I will offer some instances for your convenience that have been covered in depth before.

[Can I photograph people publicly, in the USA, without their consent?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25876/can-i-photograph-people-publicly-in-the-usa-without-their-consent)

[Photography in public places: Is it allowed or needs permission](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57587/photography-in-public-places-is-it-allowed-or-needs-permission)

[What are the laws in Australia surrounding photography in public places?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25318/what-are-the-laws-in-australia-surrounding-photography-in-public-places)

[What are my legal rights when shooting a public event?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76219/what-are-my-legal-rights-when-shooting-a-public-event)

Additionally, your point.
Beyond the obvious, I'm not sure what you're saying.
The point is,
You do need permission to enter someone's private property; that is true. That is a no-brainer, regardless of whether or not taking photographs is so unimportant to photography and is a universal action to avoid being shot.

Although it mostly concerns commercial photography, some information applies to everyone.

https://pathedits.com/blogs/tips/when-need-photography-permit-laws